# How did migration from the main to Literature.SE happen?

Tags: discussion

While on a "search and destroy" mission for my own errant comments, I noticed that this question ["Looking for a poem that I have mostly forgotten"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/looking-for-a-poem-i-have-mostly-forgotten#comment1191874_493782) was originally posted on the main site, and then "migrated" to Literature.SE.

How did that happen? Is it something only Mods have access to? The VTC menu only seems to allow for migration to meta, or ELL.

Comment: The community is only able to vote for certain migration destinations, but you can always flag a question for moderator intervention to suggest another, as moderators can dispatch questions to any stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, mods are able to migrate questions to other sites than those available to non-mods. This [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/493782/revisions) shows that I did this.