# The "needs improvement" close reason doesn't contain an option for migration

Tags: support, close-reasons, flagging, migration

When I click the "needs improvement" option I don't see any option to migrate to another website. Is this a mistake?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Btw, can you help me migrate this question to [philosophy.se]? Perhaps folks in there can have more insight about this. [What is the difference between an account and an approach?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/552652/80007)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The migration option is under **A community-specific reason**:

[image]

Clicking on 'This question belongs on another site ...' reveals another problem: Philosophy isn't listed in the so-called *migration paths*:

[image]

Only ♦ moderators can migrate questions to arbitrary sites in the network, so you'll have to raise a custom flag, as indicated in the [FAQ about migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232).

The list is kept short for reasons mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96345/295232); there's room for three more sites. Based on data from [the 10k tools](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats), adding Literature could make sense, but it's a beta site, and historically no migration paths to beta sites are created (see e.g. [As of 2020, is it possible to set up migration paths to beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354124/295232)). Other migrations are simply too rare to warrant a migration path.

[image]

Comment: this is cumbersome. Why not having an option for users to select other sites right in that panel?

Comment: @Ooker I've updated my answer with some more information about this.

Comment: @Ooker, see [Moving questions to other SE](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13324).

Comment: @Glorfindel, I know that somebody somewhere further up in the system has decided to limit the number of the options for migration, and that there probably isn't much that anybody within this community can do about it, but it should be noted that keeping the list short has quite a few downsides: the cumbersomeness that the OP points out results either in extra work for the already overworked moderators, or in some of the questions that could profit from migration simply not being moved. Incidentally nobody would ever want to migrate anything to an 'arbitrary' site.

Comment: @jsw29 I find this answer might be in your interest: [Add “Flag as Other” checkbox to “Vote to Close as Off-Topic” dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162109/260800). You can also add your point in there too